# Centering text on title bar of android app

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I've looked all over the internet and can't find an answer.  Is there a way to center the text on the title bar of an app without having to create a custom title bar?  If so, how would I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewGroup decorView= (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView(); 
LinearLayout root= (LinearLayout) decorView.getChildAt(0); 
FrameLayout titleContainer= (FrameLayout) root.getChildAt(0); 
TextView title= (TextView) titleContainer.getChildAt(0); 
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

add this code in onCreate() of your activity.

Comment: when I added your code, I was able to run the app on the emulator but not on the device.  would u know why?  thank u.

Comment: it just wouldn't open on the phone and says "unfortunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: i tried. Logcat didn't show anything.  When I hooked up the phone to my puter, I didn't get that to work at all.  It was frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Set style to your ActionBar title in the styles.xml file as,

```
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

an in MyActionBar,

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
```

where, MyActionBarTitleText is,

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    //and you can add many more customization here like textColor etc
</style>
```

Here is google's [doc.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: That seems to be a lot of work for just centering. :) OK, thank you and @user3292108!  I'll try them.

Comment: Yup at the first glance but as you get familiar you would just keep customizing the actionbar as it gives so much flexibility. :) Let me know what works out for you.

Comment: Diffy's one works fine.  When I want more customization, I'll use yours.  Thanks!